# Converting XLPagerTabStrip to swift3 causes error

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, xlpagertabstrip

I was trying to implement XLPagerTabStrip in my app and when I did, xcode asked me to convert the code. I changed the same to swift 3 but then I started getting the following errors. I am not able to fix them. Please have a look at it and guide me on how to fix the same.

Thanks.

[image]

[image]

Comment: These are from the framework. I am getting error in the framework

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `.black()` and `.white()` just write `.black` and `.white`
I hope this works recently I started swift so in swift 3 it work like this.

Answer (score 0):

Swift 3 has syntax UIColor.red or .red